# Adding user privileges to an ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net

I'm creating a web application to manage text books. There is only 1 person who can add, remove, or edit the existing items in the database. this is my first ever asp.net web app and I've researched where to edit privileges and cant seem to find it anywhere. I am using the built in register/login feature of asp.net. I need to have 1 admin account and the rest be basic users with only read access. Could anyone lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to asp.net Identity, here is a "getting started" article:

https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project